# Selecting a drop-down option using Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and having a difficult time selecting options from a drop down list (trying to select the second option).

Here is the HTML that I'm working with:

```
<div id="applicationReasonTypeIDContainer" class="appfield">

    <label id="applicationReasonTypeIDLabel" for="applicationReasonTypeID">Application Reason</label>
    <select name="appstart_international1:applicationReasonTypeID" id="applicationReasonTypeID" class="AppStart dropdown required" title="Application reason">
<option value="0">&#160;</option>
<option value="1">New Application</option>
<option value="2">Additional location</option>
<option value="3">Owner change</option>
```

I'm using XPath checker to find the XPath, and it's giving me this but it doesn't work when I try and click or select command

id('applicationReasonTypeID_listbox')/x:li[2]

What should the proper Target be for finding an option like this using XPath?

Thanks Kindly!

Comment: Can you share the html code for the drop down ?

Comment: sorry about that, I had the format incorrect but it should be correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out the problem - it's an issue with Kendo UI not supporting drop-downs properly.  Basically the workaround is the click the drop-down arrow, then use sendKeys and point to the same Target as the drop-down with the value being whatever item you want from the list, then clicking the drop-down again.  This worked for me, hopefully it helps somebody else!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the text that will be in the field this is how I do it:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("applicationReasonTypeID"))).selectByVisibleText("New Application");
```

Hope that might help.

*edit* to add correct id and text from code provided.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your answer.  I should add that I'm strictly using the IDE right now, so I guess I'm looking for the correct syntax to use in the IDE for the Target.

Comment: Ahh sorry, can't help there!

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with either of the following?

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("CustomerDropDown"))).SelectByText("Nationwide");
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("CustomerDropDown"))).SelectByIndex(1);
```